# Running a workflow within another workflow - Both terminates

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

I have been using windows workflow foundation and calling a workflow from another workflow. 
Using .Net framework 4.6.1 along with MS SQL Server 2014. The whole scenario is working absolutely fine.
However, when I deploy it to a customer environment it starts terminating without an exception or log trace. I have added detail logging (printing log statements on different lines) but it terminates on different statements. 
As debugging in customer environment is not a good idea, any pointers in identification of this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the termination only happen in the called (2nd) workflow?

How are you calling the 2nd workflow?

What does the calling (1st) workflow do when the 2nd workflow is called?

Comment: It terminates on calling to 2nd workflow, and another variable is this equation is MSDTC - which is being used in this whole scenario. 2nd workflow is being using a defined workflow activity. The whole process terminates without any log or exception stack.